# find limit based on a derivative of function in specific point

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Assume $f(x)$ is differentiable at the point $x=a$.  How do I find the limit
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{xf(a)-af(x)}{x-a}$$
The book says the answer is $f(a)-af'(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{xf(a)-af(x)}{x-a} = f(a) - a\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$$

Comment: wow. I didn't think about it. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$xf(a)-af(x)=xf(a)-af(a)+af(a)-af(x)=(x-a)f(a) -a(f(x)-f(a))$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use L'Hopital's Rule on it to get the answer, if that is allowed. If not, try to manipulate the numerator into getting a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggest that you must transform the limit to $$\lim_{x\to a}\left(f(c)-d\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)$$
where $c,d$ are $x$ or $a$.